# Ansible jinja - If loop last without newline

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

I'm having problem with ansible jinja templating. Basically i just need to list down the server_name is more readable format.

This is the variable that i defined in groups/all.yml

```
server_name:
  - domain1.mydomain.com
  - domain2.mydomain.com
  - domain3.mydomain.com
  - domain4.mydomain.com
```

And this is my template for myvhost.conf.j2

```
server_name     {% for name in server_name -%}
                  {{ name }}
                {% if loop.last -%};{%- endif -%}{% endfor %}
```

And the result is:

```
server_name     domain1.mydomain.com
                domain2.mydomain.com
                domain3.mydomain.com
                domain4.mydomain.com
                ;
```

Expected output:

```
server_name     domain1.mydomain.com
                domain2.mydomain.com
                domain3.mydomain.com
                domain4.mydomain.com;
```

I have tried several combination for the templating with whitespace control or indent but it messed up the result. Please advise kindly

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want to print **either** a newline character followed by 16 spaces, **or** `;`, after the variable value, so it is a natural requirement for an if-else statement:

```
server_name     {% for name in server_name -%}
                  {{ name }}
                {%- if not loop.last %}

                {% else %};{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This really did the trick. I can't believe how easy for you to solve it. Thanks anyway